# How would I calculate the greenhouse effect based on atmospheric composition?

Tags: planets, space, climate, astronomy, greenhouse-effect

Problem: For a known, but hypothetical planet orbiting a celestial body, how would I calculate the surface temperature after greenhouse gases?

What I know about the planet as given:

- Planetary diameter
- Percentage breakdown of atmospheric gases:

  - CO2, N2, O2, Ar, CH4 (Methane), Na, H2, He, "other"
- Distance from star
- Luminosity of star
- Surface albedo
- Total atmospheric mass

Assumptions I am making:

- "All other variables remain constant"
- The planet is completely homogenous

I've been trying to implement a simplistic model, and have been able to calculate the equilibrium temperature but not the temperature after greenhouse gases.

Ideally what I'm looking for is a function using the parameters I have that'd give me the equilibrium temperature with an atmosphere. I've reviewed several articles, but I haven't been able to make sense of their formulas to be able to create a working model.

The equation from the wiki that I found was this:
$
T_{eff} = T_V*0.7062 + T_V*0.7062*21*d_{NO}*0.099 + T_V*0.7062*d_{He}*0.218 + (T_V*\frac{0.7062}{262})*m_{CO_2} + (T_V*\frac{0.7062}{262})*m_{GH}*C
$

but I've been averse to using this one, since the `0.7062` and other magic numbers are unexplained, and given the formatting issues I'm dubious.

Formula I'm hoping to be able to create:

$
T_{eq} = \left(\frac{L*(1-A_B)}{16 \sigma \pi \alpha^2}\right)^\frac{1}{4} + \Delta T_{CO_2} + \Delta T_{N_2} + ... \\
\text{where} \\
M_{gas} = \text{mass of gas} \\
D = \text{planet diameter, in terms of earths}\\
L = \text{stellar luminosity}\\
G_c = \text{gas temperature constant}\\
\Delta T_{gas} = f(G_c, M_{gas}, D, L, A_b, \alpha, ...)
$

Links I've reviewed:

- [Greenhouse effect](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195683/how-to-calculate-the-greenhouse-effect)
- [Ammonia world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/175871/greenhouse-effect-strength-ammonia-world)
- [Terrestrial moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85786/terrestrial-moon-atmospheric-composition-validation)
- [Calculate greenhouse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152659/how-to-calculate-the-average-temperature-of-a-planet-with-greenhouse-gases)
- [Science-based calculation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152659/how-to-calculate-the-average-temperature-of-a-planet-with-greenhouse-gases) (the link to the stepwise process gave me a 403)
- [Greenhouse calculator](https://terraforming.fandom.com/wiki/Greenhouse_Calculator)
- [The hockey schtick](https://hockeyschtick.blogspot.com/2014/11/the-greenhouse-equation.html) Note: This one I deemed excessively poor because the model *cannot* calculate for 0 atmosphere, in addition to some very poor notation.

Comment: Resurrected the science-based calculation via waybackmachine http://web.archive.org/web/20150211011741/https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~showman/greenhouse.html

Comment: Insering 0 pressure should *never* give any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to calculate a surface temperature, but it relies on a constant, $\epsilon$, that doesn't appear to have an easy way to generate it.

The function is:
$$
\frac{S(1-A)}{4} = \sigma \epsilon T_e^4 + (1 - \epsilon) \sigma T_s^4
$$

For calculating $\epsilon$, my research led me to [Dr. Scott Denning](https://www.atmos.colostate.edu/people/faculty/denning/) at CSU. The answer for calculating $\epsilon$ is..."it's complicated and there's a ton of things that impact it."

But in general, $\epsilon$ has a logarithmic relationship to atmospheric pressure, where higher pressures will net higher $\epsilon$ values.